# asp.net mvc client side validation; manually calling validation via javascript for ajax posts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, validation

Under the built in client side validation (Microsoft mvc validation in mvc 2) using data annotations, when you try to submit a form and the fields are invalid, you will get the red validation summary next to the fields and the form will not post. However, I am using jquery form plugin to intercept the submit action on that form and doing the post via ajax.  This is causing it to ignore validation; the red text shows up; but the form posts anyways.  Is there an easy way to manually call the validation via javascript when I'm submitting the form? I am still kind of a javascript n00b. I tried googling it with no results and looking through the js source code makes my head hurt trying to figure it out.

Or would you all recommend that I look in to some other validation framework?  I liked the idea of jquery validate; but would like to define my validation requirements only in my viewmodel.  Any experiences with xval or anything of the sort?

Comment: Switched to jquery validation plugin and following works pretty well. Does not work with data annotations, but i will be looking in to xval to wire them together.

$("#AddCarForm").validate({ submitHandler: submitForm });

function submitForm(form) {
$("#AddCarForm").ajaxSubmit();